# QtDBus in .pro brokeCONFIG += force_debug_info?

Tags: qt-creator, qmake, qtdbus

I have a qmake/qtcreator c++ project, i set CONFIG += separate_debug_info force_debug_info in my pro file and myapp.debug was generated, today i add QT       += dbus and debug file isn't generated.
I checked the diff with my last and ok backup, here it's

```
    --- /home/eric/rpmbuild/SOURCES/QtVsPlayer-1.0.19/QtVsPlayer/QtVsPlayer.pro
+++ /home/eric/Projets/qt/QtVsPlayer/QtVsPlayer.pro
@@ -1,10 +1,10 @@
-VERSION = 1.0.19
+VERSION = 1.0.20
 DEFINES += APP_VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"
-QT       += core gui opengl multimedia multimediawidgets
+QT       += dbus core gui opengl multimedia multimediawidgets
 
 greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
 
-CONFIG += c++11 link_prl
+CONFIG += c++11 link_prl static #separate_debug_info # debug_and_release
 
 # Specifies name of the binary.
 TARGET = QtVsPlayer
@@ -85,6 +85,9 @@
     settingsform.ui \
     videoctrls.ui
 
+DBUS_ADAPTORS += local.QtVsPlayer.xml
+DBUS_INTERFACES += local.QtVsPlayer.xml
+
 TRANSLATIONS += \
     QtVsPlayer_fr_FR.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer myself but not understand!
it is the bad boy!

with

+CONFIG += static
debug file isn't generated!